# How set jackson for ignore a boolean property when it false?

Tags: java, jackson

I use Jackson, ObjectMapper.readValue(json, Class).

Have a class:

```
Component {
  private String name;
  private String someField;
  private boolean show = true; // if false -> skip it object
}
```

and extensible class:

```
ExtendedComponent extends Component {
  private List<Component> components = emptyList();// if all of object in list not showed -> skip field
}
```

and Complex class:

```
ComplexComponent extends Component {
      ExtendedComponent component;
    }
```

and json:

```
{
  "complexComponent": {
    "name": "complexName1",
    "show": true,
    "someField": "complex",
    "extendedComponent": {
      "components": [
        {
          "name": "someName1",
          "show": true,
          "someField": "someField"
        },
        {
          "name": "someName2",
          "show": false,
          "someField": "someField"
        },
        {
          "name": "someName3",
          "show": true,
          "someField": "someField"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How to get objects only with name someName1 and someName3 in ExtendedComponent ?

And how to get nullable ComplexComponent if all of components is not showed?

Comment: check this [3. Skip Objects Conditionally](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria)

Comment: you can use `Boolean` instead of `boolean` and set it `null` in case of false (in setter method of this value). Now Just  annotate that field with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`

Comment: Along a similar theme, you could create a new Enum with a single entry, for the positive/affirmative case. (that way you only end up with 2 permutations, either it is null or has a value. <-- this also works for cases where you don't have control over the setter (eg. autovalue builders)

Answer (score 11):

Depending on your version of jackson 2

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)
```

or

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

should do the trick.